# how to get admin access on certain pages

Tags: php

I have created a website that has a basic registration and login system, I have pages that I only want admins to access.

My database for the accounts has a role column with 1 user assigned as admin and the other assigned as user

AUTHENTICATE.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'feedbackdb';

// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    // Account exists, now we verify the password.
    // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['admin'] = true/false;
        header('location: home.php');


    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username!';
}

    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

And what I use to check:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'], $_SESSION['admin'])){ 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit; 
} 
?>
```

that's the code I'm using in the page,

the problem I have is it doesn't matter who I log in as it always redirects, whereas I want the page to be accessible for admins but not users.

Comment: You probably want to check the value of the session data; and kick out if they're *not* valid; so `if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){...`

Comment: do you mean the //? they are comments

Comment: re your pastebin. Using MySQL Root user for website DB access is extremely unwise and unsafe. Don't do it. Make a specific MySQL user only with limited permissions on that data that they require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to alter your query to return the `role` column.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, role FROM accounts WHERE username = ?'))
```

Next, you need to bind that value the same way you do `$id` and `$password`.

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $role);
```

Next, inside of your `password_verify()` block where you assign the other `$_SESSION` variables, set a `role` variable.

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['role'] = $role;
```

Now, on any page you want, you can block access to anyone who isn't an admin.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['role']) || $_SESSION['role'] !== 'admin') {
    //block user access
    die("You do not have permission to view this page.");
}
```

If you want to show something on a page which is only visible to admins without blocking all users from the page entirely, you could do

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {
    echo "Only admins can see this text.";
}
```

---

### Variable Cleanup

I recommend instead of creating multiple different session variable, you create a single `user` session variable containing an array of data you may need. I recommend this because it is cleaner, easier to manage, and easier to use later in your code.

Basically, replace all of your `$_SESSION` variable declarations with this:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = [
    'loggedin' => true,
    'name' => $_POST['username'],
    'id' => $id,
    'role' => $role
];
```

Then, to check if the user is an admin you would do something like this:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user']['role'] !== 'admin') {
    //block user access
    die("You do not have permission to view this page.");
}
```

And to show something for only admins without blocking all users from the page entirely:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin') {
    echo "Only admins can see this text.";
}
```

---

> NOTE: Using MySQL Root user for website DB access is extremely unwise
> and unsafe. Don't do it. Make a specific MySQL user only with limited
> permissions on that data that they require
>
> from [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536236/martin) in the
> comments.

Comment: I had ignored the pastebin, doh.

Comment: @Martin Me too at first.

Comment: @AdrianRowlands No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: if i was to also use that and put a dropdown menu in there which has links to admin pages only, would that work?

Comment: @AdrianRowlands Yes, you can put the `block user access` IF block on any page within your website and it should work.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks will have a play around with it

Comment: @AdamWinter No problem, mistakes happen :) - I would totally agree if it were Cookies though.

Comment: @AdrianRowlands I updated the answer to include a way to display something on the page only admins can see without locking every non-admin out of the entire page.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks, will have a play around with that and see if i can get a nav bar dropdown menu to work

Comment: @AdrianRowlands Sure. If you use the "Only admins can see this text" block, you should be able to put a dropdown in there which would make it only visible to admins.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ok will give it ago

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ok cant seem tofigure it ou lol, do i need tokeep the echo part?

Comment: @AdrianRowlands Nope. Feel free to post another question with what you have and send me a link to it here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921607/how-to-hide-dropdown-many-for-standard-users