# How do you hide dropdown many for specific user class

Tags: php, session

I have created a website that has a basic registration and login system, I have pages that I only admin can access.

My database for the accounts has a role column with 1 user assigned as admin and the other assigned as user

I have a navbar with a drop menu, i also have a logiin system in place which iincludes admin users, what id like to do is make the drop down menu part of the nav bar hidden for standard users and only visible for admins,

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Home.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Suppliers.php">Suppliers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Products.php">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Contact.php">Contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="FindUs.php">Find Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="profile.php">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="createPoll.php" class="dropdown-item">Create a Poll</a>
          <a href="polls.php" class="dropdown-item">Polls</a>
          <a href="read.php" class="dropdown-item">Contacts</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

authenticate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'feedbackdb';

// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, role FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $role);
    $stmt->fetch();
    // Account exists, now we verify the password.
    // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
        header('location: home.php');


    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username!';
}

    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

code to stop access to certain sites

```
<?php
Session_start();
if($_SESSION['role'] !== 'admin') {
    //block user access
    die("You do not have permission to view this page.");
}

?>
```

thats what i have gotso far

Comment: So your goal is to show this dropdown to admin users while not blocking all users from accessing the page?

Comment: yes exactly right

Comment: Why don't you just include the file for the dropdown or echo it for logged in users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch your `IF` statement to be the opposite, so everything inside the block is only shown to admins. Your current IF statement is only shown to non-admins.

You should also check if `$_SESSION['role']` is not empty before checking if it's equal to `admin` to prevent errors if the user is not logged in.

Try this:

```
//role variable IS NOT EMPTY - AND - it IS EQUAL TO "admin"
if(!empty($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {
    ?>
        <div class="header">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Home.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Suppliers.php">Suppliers</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Products.php">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="Contact.php">Contact us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="FindUs.php">Find Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="profile.php">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="createPoll.php" class="dropdown-item">Create a Poll</a>
                        <a href="polls.php" class="dropdown-item">Polls</a>
                        <a href="read.php" class="dropdown-item">Contacts</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

You will notice that, inside the IF statement, I end the PHP tag and also start it again at the end. This allows you to write plain HTML without having to use `echo`.

Comment: the dropdown menu doesnt work now? shows the admin linkbutdropdown doesnt appear it also hides the netire nav bar

Comment: @AdrianRowlands Well, you only need to put the ones only admins should see inside the IF block, everything else should be outside of that block.